# Compile Kernel module on Chromebook

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I am running an ARMv7 Chromebook with crouton. I would like to get CIFS shares mounted, but it appears that CIFS is not in the kernel. So I downloaded the same kernel version source as I am on, compiled the cifs.ko module, and attempted to load it. But I received this error:

```
# insmod cifs.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module cifs.ko: Operation not permitted
```

The module is compiled as an ARM module, I checked with file:

```
# file cifs.kocifs.ko: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1, BuildID[sha1]=e14d1772583fae478e2b113b57ce81c214e511af, not stripped
```

What gives?

Comment: are you root? Are you using the same `config` as is used on the chromebook?

Comment: My dmesg tells me: [170679.671792] Chromium OS LSM: init_module denied module="/home/user/Downloads/linux-3.10.18/fs/cifs/cifs.ko" pid=3180 cmdline="insmod cifs.ko"
That suggests Linux hardening is preventing custom kernel modules. How do I disable this??

Comment: Yes, I am root. This is not the same .config, because I do not know what the .config file should be or how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Chromium OS does not allow adding kernel modules by default. Use this script to disable module locking. https://github.com/divx118/crouton-packages/blob/master/README.md

More information on modifying the Chromium OS kernel can be found here:
https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Build-kernel-headers-and-install-Virtualbox-(x86) Generally the entire crouton repository / wiki is a lot of help.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or content changed or goes permanently offline.